# replace the same characters with different strings

Tags: php, arrays, replace

Assuming I have a string

```
$str = "abc*efg*hij*";
```

and an array

```
$arr = array("123","456","789");
```

Now I want to replace the `*`s in `$str` with the elements in `$arr` according to the positions.The first `*` replaced with `$arr[0]`,the second replaced with `$arr[1]` etc.I check the function [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php),though it accepts arrays as parameters but I found it did not work.And I cannot just use

```
$newstr = "abc{$arr[0]}efg{$arr[1]}hij{$arr[2]}"
```

because the real `$str` may be quite a long string with lots of `*`.Any good ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `*` is your only format character, try converting `*` to `%s` (also escape existing `%` to `%%`), and then using [`vsprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), which takes an array of values to pass in as format parameters:

```
$str = str_replace(array('%', '*'), array('%%', '%s'), $str);
$newstr = vsprintf($str, $arr);
echo $newstr;
```

Output:

```
abc123efg456hij789
```

Note that if you have more array elements than asterisks, the extra elements at the end simply won't appear in the string. If you have more asterisks than array elements, `vsprintf()` will emit a too-few-arguments warning and return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just keep it simple with `preg_replace()` and make use of the `$limit` argument, like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    $str = preg_replace('/\*/', $arr[$i], $str, 1);
```

but for practicality's sake, @BoltClock's answer is the better choice as it a) does not involve a loop, but more importantly b) is not forced to use a regular expression.

Comment: Good solution.I'm just planning to explode it then combine the pieces,which is obviously not a good idea:)